# Android ConstraintLayout leaves content on the outside when the content is very large

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a ScrollView which has a ConstraintLayout. I am trying to load a content, but when the content is too large, I start loosing the footer. This works fine when I have short or medium content, but only happens with very very large content.

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADUNe.png)
[This is the structure of my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjaRc.png)

I am doing the inspection with the Layout inspector and this is the result

[This is the result of the Layout Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kFqG.png)
[This is the structure of the layout in the Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jULHZ.png)

Any Idea?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/id_scv_article_detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="invisible"
tools:context=".ui.activities.contents.ArticleDetailActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/id_cnt_article_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/id_article_detail_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TitleBarTextAppearance" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/id_img_article_det"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_article_detail_toolbar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_txt_title_article_det"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:text="@string/info_not_title_defined"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_img_article_det" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_txt_summary_article_det"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:text="@string/info_not_short_text_defined"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_txt_title_article_det" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln_text_content_article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_txt_summary_article_det">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_txt_text_article_det"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"

            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text="@string/textoooo" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_cnt_gallery_article_det"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ln_text_content_article">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_txt_title_gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="@string/title_gallery"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/id_recycler_view_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_txt_title_gallery" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorLines"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLines"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_recycler_view_gallery" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_cnt_calendar_article_det"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_cnt_gallery_article_det">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/id_calendar_article"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@id/id_calendar_article"
                layout="@layout/recycler_view_calendar">

            </include>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorLines"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLines"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_calendar_article" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_cnt_resources_article_det"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_cnt_calendar_article_det">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ln_document_article"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/pdf_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_name_pdf_article"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="@string/info_not_title_defined" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/id_img_download_pdf_article"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/download_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/id_ln_document_separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#DEDEDE"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ln_document_article" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ln_link_article"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/id_ln_document_separator">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_txt_link_article"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="@string/info_not_title_defined" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_txt_copy_link_article"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:text="@string/lbl_copy_link"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/colorEdgeEffect" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_txt_go_link_article"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:text="@string/lbl_go"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/colorEdgeEffect" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/id_ln_link_separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#DEDEDE"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ln_link_article" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ln_image_article"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/id_ln_link_separator">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/id_img_img_article"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_image" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id_txt_name_img_article"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:text="@string/info_not_title_defined" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id_txt_download_img_article"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_download"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/colorEdgeEffect" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorLines"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_cnt_resources_article_det" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:text="@string/lbl_author"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_txt_author_article"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:text="@string/info_not_art_author_defined"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView13"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:text="@string/lbl_publication_date"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_txt_publication_date_article"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:text="@string/info_not_art_defined"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/id_txt_author_article"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_txt_author_article" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:text="@string/lbl_last_modification_date"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/id_txt_publication_date_article"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_txt_author_article" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_txt_last_update_date_article"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:text="@string/info_not_art_defined"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView16" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So you have to add your layout xml code to get help

Comment: Sure. I already added the layout code.

Comment: Try by wraping all view in a layout instead of scrollview

Comment: I wrapped it into a View and then the scrollView but it results into the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could not find the real problem, I decided to rewrite the layout again. I removed some of the elements that were not necessary like the intern ConstraintsLayouts and I wrapped the content in a layout, instead a scrollview like @E.Abdel suggested.

Thank you!